# regex command line linux - select all lines between two strings

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a text file with contents like this:

```
here is some super text:
  this is text that should
  be selected with a cool match
And this is how it all ends
blah blah...
```

I am trying to get the two lines (but could be more or less lines) between:

> some super text:

and

> And this is how

I am using `grep` on an ubuntu machine and a lot of the patterns I've found seem to be specific to different kinds of regex engines.

So I should end up with something like this:

```
grep "my regex goes here" myFileNameHere
```

Not sure if `egrep` is needed, but could use that just as easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how it could be done in `grep`. Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^And this is how/ {p=0}; p; /some super text:$/ {p=1}' file
```

Comment: This one actually gave me lines 2 and 3 without lines 1 and 4.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Only one problem.  It includes very strange chars at the beginning and end of my lines.  e.g. `^[[1m` and `^[[0m^[[37m^[[40m`

Comment: @carter Those are console control codes for setting colors. Change the options on the command generating the output so it doesn't output color codes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use addresses in sed:

```
sed -e '/some super text/,/And this is how/!d' file
```

`!d` means "don't output if not in the range".

To exclude the border lines, you must be more clever:

```
sed -n -e '/some super text/ {n;b c}; d;:c {/And this is how/ {d};p;n;b c}' file
```

Or, similarly, in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /some super text/ .. /And this is how/' file
```

To exclude the border lines again, change it to

```
perl -ne '$in = /some super text/ .. /And this is how/; print if $in > 1 and $in !~ /E/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to pcregrep instead of normal grep. Because normal grep won't help you to fetch multiple lines in a row.

```
$ pcregrep -M -o '(?s)some super text:[^\n]*\n\K.*?(?=\n[^\n]*And this is how)' file
  this is text that should
  be selected with a cool match
```

- `(?s)` Dotall modifier allows dot to match even newline characters also.
- `\K` Discards the previously matched characters.

From `pcregrep --help`

```
-M, --multiline              run in multiline mode
-o, --only-matching=n        show only the part of the line that matched
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

With your corpus, another way to solve the problem is by matching lines with leading whitespace, rather than using a flip-flop operator of some sort to match start and end lines. The following solutions work with your posted example.

### GNU Grep with PCRE Compiled In

```
$ grep -Po '^\s+\K.*' /tmp/corpus 
this is text that should
be selected with a cool match
```

### Alternative: Use pcregrep Instead

```
$ pcregrep -o '^\s+\K.*' /tmp/corpus 
this is text that should
be selected with a cool match
```

Comment: It won't satisfy the op's conditions.